# Using HttpResponseRedirect, but browser is not showing correct URL

Tags: django, http-redirect

I have a view that accepts input from a user and on a successful post, it redirects to another page. It's pretty much the same code in the tutorial:

```
def quex(request, id, question_number):

    next_question = int(question_number) + 1
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/quex/' + id + '/' + str(next_question)) 
    else:
        form = QuestionForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('questionnaire.html', {
        'form': form,
        'id' : id,
        'question_number' : question_number},
        RequestContext(request)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout$', 'screening.views.logout_view'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'screening.views.home'),
    url(r'^quex/new/$', 'screening.views.new_quex'),
    # others omitted
    url(r'^quex/(?P<identifier>\w{8})/(?P<question_number>\d+)/', 'screening.views.quex'),
)
```

The code seems to work and the page behaves correctly.

My problem is that the URL that appears in the client doesn't update correctly. The originating page is http://foo.com/questionnaire//1/ and the redirected page is  http://foo.com/questionnaire//2/. The old URL continues to display in the address bar of the browser even after the redirect.

The server status messages look fine:

```
[19/Aug/2013 19:15:40] "GET /quex/P54C9UCS/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3225
[19/Aug/2013 19:15:44] "POST /quex/P54C9UCS/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Aug/2013 19:15:44] "GET /quex/P54C9UCS/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3206
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the browser to show the right URL?

Edit: I did a bit more testing. Chrome, Safari (on OS X and iOS), and Firefox display the URL as described above. But [Browser Khmer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browser-khmer/id492012135?mt=8) on iOS shows the url as `http://foo.com/quex/<id>/1/#/quex/<id>/2/` .

Comment: better use django's reverse() to build the url inside HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: Inspect the value of `next_question`. Is it really `2`?

Comment: @dan_klasson Yes. next_question really is 2. The page displays this number. In other words, the first time that the page displays the url is http://foo.com/quex/<id>/1/, but the page says Question 2.

However, if I POST without inputting an answer, the page re-displays so that I'm forced to enter a response. At this point, the URL displays correctly.

Comment: @user640916 Can try. Why is it better?

Comment: @user640916 I switched to using reverse(), but the problem persists.

Comment: a) it will ensure that your arguments really do match the regex, e.g. the exact length of id as 8 b) using reverse with named url patterns instead of hardcoding them, makes them much less likely to break/much easier to replace when you need to change the url format. Btw the view name 'quex' in your url pattern does not match 'questionnaire'?

Comment: @user640916 Thanks. It does match in my code. I fixed the typo in this except.

Comment: @benevolentprof Did you figure this out?  I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: what version of django are you running? also please provide form code, QuestionForm() as well as the template questionnaire.html. So we can properly reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it, but:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout$', 'screening.views.logout_view'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'screening.views.home'),
    url(r'^quex/new/$', 'screening.views.new_quex'),
    # others omitted
    url(r'^quex/(?P<identifier>\w{8})/(?P<question_number>\d+)/$', 'screening.views.quex', name='quex-view'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


def quex(request, identifier, question_number):

    next_question = int(question_number) + 1
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass

            response_url = reverse_lazy('quex-view', kwargs={'identifier':identifier, 'question_number':next_question})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reponse_url) 
    else:
        form = QuestionForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('questionnaire.html', {
        'form': form,
        'identifier' : identifier,
        'question_number' : question_number},
        RequestContext(request)
```

Comment: this should work, but i would use reverse instead of reverse_lazy (from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse)

Answer (score 0):

Your last quex regex ends in /, not /$. Change that first. You say you've switched to reverse in the view  so that single regex change should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of you are calling views method as a recursion. here return HttpResponseRedirect('/quex/' + id + '/' + str(next_question))  is call again same method only difference is request.method will change from POST to GET. and second time as a get method this will call return render_to_response and you will see page. I hape you will get my through.

**Change your code like this:**

```
def quex(request, id, question_number):
    next_question = int(question_number) + 1
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            # Next line I have written, so you will get same value of question_number as you get after returning from HttpResponseRedirect
            question_number =  next_question + 1 
    form = QuestionForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('questionnaire.html', {
        'form': form,
        'id' : id,
        'question_number' : question_number},
        RequestContext(request)
```

This code will work as your current code. without any bug.
Hope this will help full to you.

Answer (score 0):

What the browser shows in the URL bar will depend on your client-side code:

- simple HTML forms will redirect correctly.
- jquery's `$.ajax()` call will [not redirect by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call), so even though the code works, the client does not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
def quex(request, identifier, question_number):

    next_question = int(question_number) + 1
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/quex/' + identifier + '/' + str(next_question)) 
    else:
        form = QuestionForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('questionnaire.html', {
        'form': form,
        'id' : identifier,
        'question_number' : question_number})
```

1. your `render_to_response()` is missing the trailing `)`
2. the 3rd argument to `render_to_response()` is optional. I usually leave it off. However I would pass it in as a named argument as-per the documentation. [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)
3. **finally**: your `def quex(request, id, question_number):` should be `def quex(request, identifier, question_number):` in order to match the url pattern. Also change the id references in the body of quex to be identifier ( which I included in the sample code)